# Why is declaring self not required in structures where it's required in classes?

Tags: swift

Why is declaring `self` not required in structures where it's required in classes? I don't know if there are other examples where this is the case but with escaping closures, it is. If the closure is non-optional (and thus non-escaping), there is no requirement to declare `self` in either of the two.

```
class SomeClass {
    let someProperty = 1
    
    func someMethod(completion: (() -> Void)?) {}
    
    func anotherMethod() {
        someMethod {
            print(self.someProperty) // declaring self is required
        }
    }
}

struct SomeStruct {
    let someProperty = 1
    
    func someMethod(completion: (() -> Void)?) {}
    
    func anotherMethod() {
        someMethod {
            print(someProperty) // declaring self is not required
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that there's truly a good answer for this, but if this is really demonstrative of your use case, you may want to just capture `someProperty` instead. You don't need the whole object.

Comment: See [SE-0269 - Increase availability of implicit self in @escaping closures when reference cycles are unlikely to occur](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0269-implicit-self-explicit-capture.md)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of including `self` when using properties inside an escaping closure (whether optional closure or one explicitly marked as `@escaping`) with reference types is to make the capture semantics explicit. As the compiler warns us if we remove `self` reference:

> Reference to property 'someProperty' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit.

But there are no ambiguous capture semantics with structs. You are always dealing with a copy inside the escaping closure. It is only ambiguous with reference types, where you need `self` to make clear where the strong reference cycle might be introduced, which instance you are referencing, etc.

---

By the way, with class types, referencing `self` in conjunction with the property is not the only way to make the capture semantics explicit. For example, you can make your intent explicit with a “capture list”, either:

- Capture the property only:

  ```
   class SomeClass {
       var someProperty = 1

       func someMethod(completion: @escaping () -> Void) { ... }

       func anotherMethod() {
           someMethod { [someProperty] in    // this captures the property, but not `self`
               print(someProperty)
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- Or capture `self`:

  ```
   class SomeClass {
       var someProperty = 1

       func someMethod(completion: @escaping () -> Void) { ... }

       func anotherMethod() {
           someMethod { [self] in            // this explicitly captures `self`
               print(someProperty)
           }
       }
   }
  ```

Both of these approaches also make it explicit what you are capturing.

Comment: But how is it with SwiftUIs @State var properties? When we access them in a completion block we won't be accessing a copy of the struct.

Comment: The compiler requires `self` qualifier whenever there is a potential strong reference cycle. But SwiftUI `View` is a `struct`, so there is no strong reference cycle risk (because the `View` is not a reference type). So, the compiler will not require an explicit `self` when specifying a property of the `View` value type.

Answer (score 3):

For classes, closures provide a mechanism to increment a reference count, thus "keeping the object alive".

*Maybe* you're okay with just capturing `someProperty`. Maybe not! The compiler doesn't know if you're using a closure in order to increment the reference, so it makes you be explicit about your intentions.

Not only is *that* a non-issue with structs, but so is the possibility of mutation, which is strictly disallowed.

Let's say you wanted `anotherMethod` to allow mutation of *any kind*, in a struct. You could start by marking it as mutating…

```swift
struct SomeStruct {
  func someMethod(completion: (() -> Void)?) {}

  mutating func anotherMethod() {
    someMethod {
      self
    }
  }
}
```

…but no, that's an error:

> Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

Capture `self`, though…

```swift
  mutating func anotherMethod() {
    someMethod { [self] in
      self
    }
  }
```

…and that's fine.

And it's also the only option Swift allows. When you use an escaping closure from within a struct, you can only use an immutable capture of an instance. i.e. `[self] in` is implicit, for nonmutating methods.

This can yield unexpected results. Be careful.

```swift
struct SomeStruct {
  var someProperty = 1

  func anotherMethod() {
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
      print(someProperty)
    }
  }
}

var s = SomeStruct()
s.anotherMethod() // 1, even though it's printed after the following reassignment 
s.someProperty = 2
s.anotherMethod() // 2
```

I think it helps to think about what method syntax is shorthand for.

```swift
s.anotherMethod()
```

is really

```swift
SomeStruct.anotherMethod(s)()
```

You can visualize the immutability there, because there's no &.